# Spatial Regression Using Panel Data

Tags: spatial-statistics, regression, stata

I am analyzing a spatial panel dataset using the XSMLE package in Stata. My units are a subset of US states (11) and my panel is strongly balanced.

- The package returns estimations for Main, Spatial, Variance, Direct and Indirect betas. Is there a resource someone can recommend explaining how to interpret these statistics? I've read the presentation that Belotti, Hughes and Mortari (2013) created on XSMLE, but they don't discuss why the estimations are presented in this fashion.
- If a standard Hausman test indicates that an RE model is appropriate, does that results extend to a spatial panel?
- What's the best way to assess high leverage observations when running a spatial panel? Should I just estimate a pooled OLS model and then calculate DFBETA and Cook's D or is there another approach?

Comment: You *may* have better luck with this question on [Cross-Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). There are a few people here that could probably answer, but CV is specifically focused on stats.

Comment: I face same problem interpreting main and the variance where can I find explanation?and why stata reports with no explanation